# Heap size: getRuntime().maxMemory() is much less than -Xmx parameter

Tags: java, memory, jvm

This is my `-xmx` seting in  IDEA

```
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
```

64bit system, 16GB memory.

I don't know why the result of `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` is much less than 8G. Actually, it does not change according to `-xmx`.

The program throws heap space after exceeding this value.

Anyone can help me?

This is my result of `maxMemory()`: `3803185152`

Comment: The Xmx settings are the ones that are applied to the IDE itself: **IDEA** will take at most 8GB of heap memory with those settings. This has no effect on Java process launched from *within* Java. Just edit the launch configuration if you want to affect those.

Comment: Joachim, consider converting your comment into an answer.